# Unable to update data source configuration in Forena Report for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I was trying to update one of the data source of my forena configuration. I first update the uri address. After I clicked Updated the forena module broke. I'm sure the problem is that one of the Data Source (the one I updated) can't connect to the database because I didn't update the password. But now, eveytime I click in Configure in my Data source I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object
>   in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/forena/plugins/FrxPDO.inc
>   on line 63

Becuase of this error I can't correct the password.

The drupal log shows the following:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'bitnami'@'54.204.20.212' (using password: YES)

I'm thinking there most be a config file somewhere in the htdocs directory but I can't find it.

Can somebody guide on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Claudia

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

It seems that bitnami user is trying to access to the dtabase. By default, bitnami user has not privileges to access to the drupal database.

Check in installdir/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/default/settings.php
the user and the password of the drupal database. You could try execute the action with these parameters. By default, your database name should be bitnami_drupal, and your user bn_drupal.

You also can change the privileges for bitnami user:

`$ /installdir/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
grant all privileges on bitnami_drupal.* TO 'bitnami'@'localhost' identified by 'not_easy_password'`

If you want to create a new database, please follow this link:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/MySQL#How_to_create_a_database_for_a_custom_application.3f

I hope it helps

David